# why are the extreme points equivalent to basic feasible solutions in a linear programming problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

Let extreme points be the set X={x greater or equal to 0 given Ax=b for vector x and b} and a point x is extreme if for all y,z in X, x=(1-a)y+az for a=[0,1]

Basic Feasible solution x is if for A be matrix m*n, there are at most m non-zero entries.

I would like to see why it is equivalent (the proof) as i dont understand some notes given online (http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~qb204/teaching/optim_2019.pdf, theorem   3.1)
Thank you!

Comment: You mean that a convex set is given as $X=\{x\ge 0:Ax=b\}$ and the vertices or extremal points of $X$ are those that can not be represented as (non-trivial) convex combination of other points of $X$? And then you allude to a statement about Lagrange duality?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in X$ be a feasible point and $I\subset\{1,2,...,n\}$ be the subset of indices so that $x_{i}=0$ if and only if $i\in I$. Then if $$|I|+m<n$$ the expanded system
$$
Av=0,~v_i=0~~\forall i\in I
$$
has a non-zero solution by simple rank considerations, the solution space of that system has dimension at least $n-(m+|I|)>0$.

Take such a vector $v$ and observe that $x+tv\in X$ for small positive and negative $t$. Take an $\varepsilon$ so that $x\pmεv\in X$, then $x=\frac12(x+εv)+\frac12(x-εv)$ is not an extremal point of the set.

Thus in any extremal point of $X$, there are at least $n-m$ components that are zero, or in other words, at most $m$ non-zero entries.